# Copy range between sheets to last row

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for simple, elegant solutions using the range in its current form to append under another Worksheet's last row.

Range:

```
        Sheets("conf_9").Columns(5).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec_9").Columns(9)
        Sheets("conf_9").Columns(6).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec_9").Columns(10)
        Sheets("conf_9").Columns(7).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec_9").Columns(7)
        Sheets("conf_9").Columns(8).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec_9").Columns(8)
        Sheets("conf_9").Columns(12).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec_9").Columns(6)
```

Several responses to a similar question seem overly complicated and incompatible to the `Columns` usage - yes, I am new to VBA. For example, inserting the expression `Columns(number) & last row` syntax is rejected.

Many thanks.

Comment: `Destination:=Sheets("Rec_9").Cells(lastRow, 9)` and so on. But you can't copy the entire column... it won't fit unless you paste it into row 1 of the destination sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It is not necessary to copy whole columns. The code calculates the last filled row of the sheet to copy the column and the first empty row of the target sheet column:

```
Sub AppendToOtherSheet()
  Dim shC As Worksheet, wsR As Worksheet, lastRowC As Long, lastRowR As Long
  Set shC = Sheets("conf_9")
  Set wsR = Sheets("Rec_9")
   lastRowC = shC.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   lastRowR = wsR.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
   
   shC.Range("E2:E" & lastRowC).Copy Destination:=wsR.Cells(lastRowR, 9)
   shC.Range("F2:F" & lastRowC).Copy Destination:=wsR.Cells(lastRowR, 10)
   shC.Range("G2:G" & lastRowC).Copy Destination:=wsR.Cells(lastRowR, 7)
   shC.Range("H2:H" & lastRowC).Copy Destination:=wsR.Cells(lastRowR, 8)
   shC.Range("L2:L" & lastRowC).Copy Destination:=wsR.Cells(lastRowR, 6)
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that all columns have the same number of rows, and the sheet where from the columns are copied has column headers.

If the columns in discussion do not have the same number of rows, `lastRowC` and `lastRowR` must be calculated for each column to be copied. If no column headers, the range to be copied will start (for instance) from "E1" instead of "E2" in the first copying code line.

Comment: @Geoffrey Turner: Did you test the code I posted above?

Comment: Beautiful logic and ran perfectly. Thank you explaining the rationale.

Comment: @Geoffrey Turner: Glad I could help! But in su h a case, when somebody posts a convenient answer, we tick the code left side check box, to make it **accepted ansewr**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that tte code workwd. :)